# Nreco.VideoConverter, how to save the converted file name to database?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

How can i get the resulting file name after the conversion that is converted using nreco.videoconverter my requirement is to save the file path to database

```
                            var converter = new NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter();

                            converter.ConvertMedia(file, Path.Combine(filepath,Path.GetFileName(file).Split('.')[0]) + ".mp4", "mp4");


                            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.CommandText = "sp_videofilepathupdate";
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path",);
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            con.Close();
```

i have tried to pass the < Path.GetFileName(file).Split('.')[0]) + ".mp4"> but its saving the old file name itself that is file.flv but after conversion the file name that is saving to local folder is file.mp4. How can i achive this to save it to database. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass the foldername with what i have tried.

```
`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path",@"Uploads/"+Path.GetFileName(file).Split('.')[0]+".mp4");
`
```